# Strange behaviour of IsError

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a column with dates formatted as text, missing values are marked with `-`.

I try to create an expression (SQL, not VBA) which converts that column to date, converting missing values to `0`:

- This expression works as expected:
  `IIf([column]="-",0,CDate([column])`
- However if I try to make somethin more generic, looking for all non-date inputs I get `#Error` for all non-date:
  `IIf(IsError(CDate([column])),0,CDate([column])`

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try and use `isDate()` as an alternative:

```
IIf(IsDate([column]),CDate([column],0)
```

Notice that I have swapped the true and false part around in the `iif()` as the expression has changed.

Although, if the only alternative to a date is the dash `-` symbol, which you have used in the first expression I believe that the `IsNumeric()` function would also work.

Comment: it's just giving the same error as my expression with `IsError`:(

Comment: @MátéJuhász: What if you omit the first CDate? `IIf(IsDate([column]), ...`

Comment: @LiamH: that's still the same